# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Geographic Information Systems' [second moderator election](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: matt wilkie] [image: iant]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1204027/0).

Comment: Congratulations and welcome to our team. Thank you to all who participated in the 2013 Community Moderator Election.

Comment: Whew, that was close! Congratulations to both.

Comment: I, too, look forward to working with Matt and Ian. But to the other candidates, please know that you received many votes, too: it was a remarkably close contest. I wish to extend my deep appreciation for your efforts--especially those of you who answered all the questions!--and want you to know that I will be grateful for your ongoing contributions to our site and your help in moderating it by means of the privileges earned by your high reputations, whether or not you have a "diamond." Through your activities as reviewers and on the meta site, you have shown your worthiness to be moderators.

Comment: Congratulations to Matt and Ian, and commisserations to @NathanW who went down narrowly in a great fight.  Thanks also to those who helped conduct the election and the other candidates.  It was the first election I had contested since going for Moonta High School Captain a few years back and it was exciting to participate!

Comment: Congrats Matt and Ian!

Comment: Congrats to you both.  It was pretty close :)

Comment: Excellent race all around! Congratulations Matt and Ian.

Comment: Congratulation to you Both!

Comment: Welcome to the team and congratulations to both of you!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you, and thanks for commitment!

Comment: Looks like @iant is still on vacation and hasn't visited the site for about a week.  He likely doesn't know he's a moderator.  That will be a good surprise for him.

Comment: Congratulations Matt and Ian :)

Comment: thanks for the vote of confidence - now I'm back on the internet I'll start figuring out moderating

Answer (score 18):

Thank you everyone who voted, regardless of who your choices were. I'll constantly endeavour to be worthy of your confidence in me in this role. I for one was pleased with the selections available and would have been happy with other outcomes, enough so I didn't even vote for myself ;-)

Ian, Bill, Mapperz and Anita : I look forward to working together with you in the coming year as we continue to shepherd our little community along.

Answer (score 14):

## Tally of the voting

[image: Table of votes]

Lighter circles and larger fonts correspond to larger counts.  Rows designate votes for first, second, and third places.  Columns designate candidates (using both initials where available or else the first two letters of their names).  The rightmost column "--" tallies missing votes.  195 people voted.

## Map of the voting

This map shows *associations* in the voting: arrows point towards a candidate from candidates who received higher priority.  Colors and thicknesses correspond to the numbers of voters who favor one candidate over another.

[image: Map]

(No, it's not easy to read, but you can derive a lot of information from it that is not available in the table.)

Comment: Brilliant Bill!  going to be used in a carto class so keep it updated!!! Regards